# Because of a pedal rattle and squeak should I remove my pedals off and how?

Tags: repair, pedals

The pedals are little rough and rattle quietly. The spindle creaks sometimes. It is not so much its condition but rather that it fail that worries me. I see no way to get the pedals off separately with black plastic end and the main spindle has a white plastic end.
I don't expect to get any help from a bicycle shop. One wanted to charge me 8000 yen or $80  to fix it. Surely it is something like contaminated bearings and internals not being tight.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The pedals are unlikely to fail in a way that causes a safety issue. In theory, they could jam/seize up and the pedal rotate with the crank, but things have to be pretty bad for that to happen.

The rattily/noisy bearing may be able to be serviced, but often with cheap pedals they are not designed for servicing, and its easier to replace them with new pedals.  You may want to try a squirt of aerosol grease into the bearings if you can access them.

The pedals are easy to remove with a pedal wrench - just remember left hand pedal has a left hand thread so turns 'the wrong way' to loosen.

Refer https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/pedal-installation-and-removal

If you  wanted to have a go at servicing the bearings, there is usually a nut under a plastic cap on the end of the pedal. You need to remove the plastic cap and use a socket to remove the nut.

Comment: Agreed.  Sadly those pedals don't look like serviceable ones, and forcing some lubrication is about the best that can be done for them.

Comment: It should be noted that removing pedals of that style and vintage usually requires a good vocabulary.